# Olympiad Inequality AM-GM (easy)

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Prove that
$(1 + x + y)^2 + (1 + y + z)^2 + (1 + z + x)^2 ≤ 3(x + y + z)^2$, with equality if and only if $x = y = z = 1$ ($xyz \ge 1$) ($x,y,z$ positive reals)

This simplifies to

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 4(xy + yz + zx) - 4(x + y + z) \geq 3$

I am looking for a proof using AM-GM preferably.

Comment: Is the "2" meant to be "Squared". Please refer to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to make your question more readable :)

Comment: yes, i fixed the problem

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant your question to be worded differently, but the way it's worded it's trivial. as x,y,z >= 1, 1 + x + y <= x + y + z, and same with the other expressions.

Comment: you have read the question wrong, there are no commas between xyz>=1. (it is the product)

Answer (score 4):

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 4(xy + yz + zx) - 4(x + y + z) =(x+y+z-2)^2-4+2(xy + yz + zx)$$
Now, by AM-GM:
$$x+y+z\ge3\sqrt[3]{xyz}\ge3\tag{1}$$
$$xy+yz+zx\ge3\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}\ge3\tag{2}$$
which pretty much settles the matter:
$$\underbrace{(x+y+z-2)^2}_{\ge1}-4+2(\;\underbrace{xy + yz + zx}_{\ge3}\;)\ge1-4+6=3$$